# Python's sub-process returns truncated output when using PIPE to read very long outputs

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, stdout

We have a rasterization utility developed in NodeJS that converts HTML string to the Base64 of the rendered HTML page. The way we are using it is by using sub-process module to run the utility and then reading its STDOUT by using PIPE. The basic code that implements this is as follows:

```
    from subprocess import run, PIPE
    result = run(['capture', tmp_file.name, '--type', 'jpeg'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, check=True)
    output = result.stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

The output contains the Base64 string of the rendered HTML page. As Base64 is very large for large pages, I have noticed that for some HTML pages, the output is truncated and is not complete. But, this happens randomly so Base64 could be correct for a page one time but truncated next time. It is important to mention here that I'm currently using threading (10 threads) to convert HTML to Base64 images concurrently so that might play a role here.

I analyzed this in detail and found out that, under the hood, the subprocess.run method uses the **_communicate** method which in turn uses the **os.read()** method to read from the PIPE. I printed its output and found out that it's also truncated and that's why STDOUT is truncated. Strange behavior altogether.

Finally, I was able to solve this by using a file handle instead of the PIPE and it works perfectly.

```
with open(output_filename, 'w+') as out_file:
    result = run(['capture', tmp_file.name, '--type', 'jpeg'], stdout=out_file, stderr=PIPE, check=True)
```

I'm just curious why the PIPE fails to handle complete output and that too, randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run subprocess, the command gets executed on bash.
When you use PIPE as stdout, internally bash stores data in a temp variable, which has hard limit of 128 Kb. anything that spills over 128kb gets truncated.

Best way to handle large data is to capture the output in a file.

Comment: Yes that's what I did. Dumped the data to a temporary file and then read it from there. It's very stable now.